# How can I prevent a WFS layer from refreshing on pan/zoom?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, wfs, extents

I'm using python to load a WFS layer into QGIS 3.34 - code snippet below. I've included a bounding box parameter within the url based on the current canvas extent at the time the script is run. The layer loads successfully, but when I pan/zoom, the layer extent is refreshed each time and all features within the updated canvas extent are shown.

If I manually load the WFS layer through the Data Source Manager, the bbox parameters work as I'd like and only those features within the defined extent are loaded. Panning/zooming doesn't refresh the loaded extents.

Ideally using python, how can I prevent this refresh and keep only those features within the canvas extent at the time the script is run?

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
extent = canvas.extent()
uri = f"https://api.os.uk/features/v1/wfs?version=2.0.0&service=WFS&request=GetFeature&typename=osfeatures:WaterNetwork_WatercourseLink&bbox={extent.xMinimum()},{extent.yMinimum()},{extent.xMaximum()},{extent.yMaximum()},EPSG:27700&srsname=EPSG:27700&key=[MY KEY]"

wfs_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'WaterNetwork_WatercourseLink', 'WFS')
print(uri)
project.addMapLayer(wfs_layer)
```

Comment: It returns me `False` when I tried `print(wfs_layer.isValid())`

Comment: That'll be because I've removed my key from the end. You'll need a key.

Comment: Indeed, I see now `&key=[MY KEY]` in the end

Comment: A crude option that works around WFS completely would be to Clip the layer to the current extent using processing.run()